# what should be database schema for online voting app

Tags: database, normalization

I want to develop an app where Events/Question would be posted by admin and user will vote or answer. Here question can be of three different type and each type can have different option.Admin can view reports about each question
E.g

- WHQuestion: What is right age for marriage? (1) >20 (2)=20 (3)20<
- Voting:Who is best captain (1)ABC (2)PQR n so on......
- YesNoQuestion: Is Dhoni a good captain? (1)Yes (2)No

So I am confused here about the database schema and tables. How should i manage them?

Answer (score 1):

All questions are multiple choice with one or zero correct answers. So: One question, some answers, one optional correct answer.

- **Question**: *question_no*, text
- **Answer**: *question_no, answer_no*, text

As to how to store which answer per question is correct, there are two options:

1. Store the answer_no in the question record. I consider this the better option. A dbms featuring deferred Constraints (so a question record can reference an answer record and vice versa) would be a good thing to have here. If there is no correct answer the answer_no is null.
2. Have a flag in the answers table and then mark one answer per question as correct and the others as incorrect. This would be appropriate if there were multiple correct answers per question possible. For one correct answer, however, this would be the worse option of the two. To guarantee data consistency you would apply some special check, which can be a bit complicated (for instance a function index to guarantee uniqueness). For no correct answer you could store the same value or even null for all answers. However, you must see the answers to find out that this is a vote question. So again, option 1 is the better choice where you see this immediately in the question record.